# How to convert SQLite query into MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How to convert this SQLite query into MongoDB query with aggregation framework

SQLite query:

```
"
FROM car
    WHERE (@make is NULL OR @make = make)
    AND (@model is NULL OR @model = model)
    AND (@minPrice is NULL OR @minPrice <= price)
    AND (@maxPrice is NULL OR @maxPrice >= price)
"
```

i tried to convert into mongodb aggregation famework
and every thing runs as expected

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { $or: [{ make: null }, { make: "BMW" }] },
        { $or: [{ model: null }, { model: "320" }] },
        { $or: [{ price: null }, { price: { $gte: 1000 } }] },
        { $or: [{ price: null }, { price: { $lte: 80000 } }] },
      ],
    },
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0, make: 1, model: 1, price: 1 } },
];
```

but when not matching a "make" it returns nothing

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { $or: [{ make: null }, { make: "asds" }] },
        { $or: [{ model: null }, { model: "320" }] },
        { $or: [{ price: null }, { price: { $gte: 1000 } }] },
        { $or: [{ price: null }, { price: { $lte: 80000 } }] },
      ],
    },
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0, make: 1, model: 1, price: 1 } },
];
```

Comment: Here are guidelines to convert SQL to Aggregation query: [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/index.html).

Comment: thanks a lot
i tried to convert and every thing works as expected
but when "make" not match it returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by replace `{field: null}` to `{field: {$exists: <false> || <true> } }`

show mongodb [$exists operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in details

> ***so i have this 'car' collection***

```
[
 {make: 'Audi', model: 'A2', price: 13999},
 {make: 'BMW', model: '116', price: 12999},
 {make: 'BMW', model: 'X1', price: 18999},
 {make: 'BMW', model: '320', price: 24000},
 {make: 'BMW', model: '320', price: 50999},
 {make: 'Ford', model: 'Fiesta', price: 14999},
 {make: 'Mazda', model: '6', price: 13999},
 {make: 'Merces-Benz', model: '200', price: 38999},
 {make: 'Mazda', model: '6', price: 16999},
 {make: 'Mazda', model: 'e250', price: 11999},
]
```

> ***and if i search about***

1. make = 'BMW'
2. model = 'asd' (value is not provided in our db collection)
3. minPrice = 1000
4. maxPrice = 40000

> ***will return this result***

```
 {make: 'BMW', model: '116', price: 12999},
 {make: 'BMW', model: 'X1', price: 18999},
 {make: 'BMW', model: '320', price: 24000},
```

without this document that has 'price = 50999'

```
{make: 'BMW', model: '320', price: 50999}
```

***that is mean "price" condition is working as well***

> ***let's code this aggregation***

i have a pipeline that have two stages '$match' and '$project'

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { $or: [{ make: { $exists: false } }, { make: "BMW" }] },
        { $or: [{ model: { $exists: true } }, { model: "asd" }] },
        { $or: [{ price: { $exists: false } }, { price: { $gte: 1000 } }] },
        { $or: [{ price: { $exists: false } }, { price: { $lte: 50000 } }] },
      ],
    },
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0, make: 1, model: 1, price: 1 } },
];
```

***in this "$or" condition***

```
{ $or: [{ make: { $exists: false } }, { make: "BMW" }] }
```

***will check if "make" field is exist or not.***

***if not exist ($exists: false) will continue to the next condition that is in "$or" operator and if is true will continue to the next "$or" condition in '$and' operator,***

***if exist ($exists: true) will only continue to the next "$or" condition in '$and' operator and so on.***